# What is the difference between CROSS JOIN and CROSS JOIN TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join

In the following code :

```
SELECT ... FROM ... CROSS JOIN TABLE ... WHERE ...;
```

What does CROSS JOIN TABLE mean ?

I searched on the net, but all I can find is about CROSS JOIN only.

I suppose CROSS JOIN TABLE acts on a table, meaning a table like that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ... AS TABLE OF ...;
```

Here is the full query :

```
SELECT prog.id_oct_prog_tran_a_participati, prog.code_ressource, prog.instant_depart, prog.commentaire, prog.en_hors_economie_de_comb, discr.delai, discr.valeur_point, MOD(delai, 60) AS H24
          FROM req_prog prog
            CROSS JOIN TABLE(POINTS_DISCRETS(pIdChronique=>id_chr_substitution)) discr
          WHERE horizon <= 'J1'
            AND delai > 0
          ORDER BY id_oct_prog_tran_a_participati, instant_depart, horizon, delai
```

`POINTS_DISCRETS` is a function that returns an element of type `TYPE_TAB_POINT`. And `TYPE_TAB_POINT` is a type that the DBA created as following :

```
create or replace TYPE "TYPE_TAB_POINT" AS TABLE OF TYPE_POINT;
```

Where `TYPE_POINT` is a type created as following :

```
create or replace TYPE "TYPE_POINT" AS OBJECT
(
ID_CHRONIQUE NUMBER,
HORIZON      VARCHAR2(2),
NUM_POINT    NUMBER(4),
DELAI        NUMBER(5),
VALEUR_POINT FLOAT
);
```

So, as you see here, `CROSS JOIN TABLE` acts on a table but not a table as we usually mean in a database, more a table like an array.

Is it the case ? And, if yes, how can it be considered like a *real* table ?

Comment: Please post our full query?

Comment: I edited my question. Any idea ?

Comment: It's not `cross join table` it's a `cross join` with a `table(..)` expression.

Answer (score 6):

You're parsing the statement incorrectly, which is confusing you I think. `CROSS JOIN TABLE` isn't one fragment; it's a`CROSS JOIN` (but could be any join type) between your real table `req_prog` and, separately, `TABLE(...)` to tell the query to treat the return value of the function call as a table.

`TABLE(...)` is the [table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#sthref6751):

> The table_collection_expression lets you inform Oracle that the value of collection_expression should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations. The collection_expression can be a subquery, a column, a function, or a collection constructor.

Here `POINTS_DISCRETS` is the collection constructor - returning `TYPE_TAB_POINT`, which is a collection, most of which you already figured out.

In this case your collection is a table of objects, and treating it as a table allows you both to join and to refer to the attributes of the object that forms each 'row' as if it were a column. The `TABLE()` is aliased as `discr`, so you are able to refer to `discr.delai` - where `delai` is one of the attributes of the `TYPE_POINT` type. If you were using an inner or outer join, rather than a cross join, you would use the same construction in the join condition, e.g. `ON discr.x = prog.x`. Once you apply the table collection expression you just treat it as a table in the rest of the statement.

Comment: Thank you, perfectly understood !